Understanding the reasoning behind an OOM invokation
I'm currently analyzing an OOM-killer log and there are some things that I cannot make sense of. Bear with me, I'm still new in the rabbithole of understanding the memory management in linux.
The OOM message begins with
VM Thread invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x6200ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE), nodemask=(null), order=0, oom_score_adj=0

From my understanding, some process requested one page (order=0) in the HIGHUSER_MOVABLE memory "region" (if that's a term that can be applied here). Later in the log:
Node 0 Normal free:65568kB min:65500kB low:161416kB high:257332kB active_anon:92072264kB inactive_anon:3184756kB active_file:464kB inactive_file:1004kB unevictable:0kB writepending:16kB present:97517568kB managed:95921624kB mlocked:0kB kernel_stack:6448kB pagetables:197836kB bounce:0kB free_pcp:1468kB local_pcp:0kB free_cma:0kB

That is the first puzzling thing because free is clearly greater than min (not by much, I admit). I finally stumble upon the real reason the OOM-killer ran
0 pages HighMem/MovableOnly

But what I don't understand, is that if read right before this in the logs, I have this information
Node 0 Normal: 5187*4kB (UMEH) 2439*8kB (UMEH) 974*16kB (UMEH) 131*32kB (UMEH) 97*64kB (UMH) 1*128kB (H) 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 0*4096kB = 66372kB

Which, if my understanding of the UMEH and UMH is correct, indicates that there is still free memory in the HIGHUSER_MOVABLE "region". Additionaly, if I compute the available memory based on the Node 0 Normal line, I get a different value from the free value indicated in the other Node 0 Normal line.
Hence my questions

Given an OOM-killer invokation log, where is the correct information of the remaining memory
Why is there, according to the Node 0 Normal line still more than enough memory available in the HIGHUSER_MOVABLE "region" but yet no pages seem to be available.

Note: This is a Debian 10 with kernel 4.19.0-25 on an x86_64 processor, if that is of any interest in answering the question

VM Thread ? Is this the Java VM thread ? owned by root or other priviledged user ?

Could you also please post the output of sysctl -a | grep min_free_kbytes (as root)

@MC68020 Output is vm.min_free_kbytes = 67584, as to the VM thread, I'm honestly not sure. The java process that ended up being killed had PID 20639 whereas the output under the line that mentions VM Thread is CPU: 11 PID: 20646 Comm: VM Thread Not tainted 4.19.0-25-amd64 #1 Debian 4.19.289-2, so it's not a thread of the JVM.
I suspect the process that invoked the oom-killer was a process linked to an SFTP connection that happened on the server, as to why it says VM Thread, I have no clue.

vm.min_free_kbytes = 67584 ? Well then, this is definitely higher than what was reported "free" (free:65568kB). Enough to trigger the OOM-killer per se then.
